# Enumerating Object.keys() in node.js - strange issue

Tags: node.js

There is an issue with enumerating Object.keys() in node.js that I do not understand. With the following code:

```
Object.prototype.tuple = function() {
  var names = Object.keys(this);
  console.log("Dump of names:");
  console.log(names);
  console.log("FOR loop using indexes:");
  for (var k = 0; k < names.length; k++)
  {
    console.log(names[k]);
  }
  console.log("FOR loop using enumeration:");
  for (var z in names)
  {
    console.log(z);
  }
  return this;
};

var x = {a:0, b:0, c:0}.tuple();
```

I get the following results on the console:

```
Dump of names:
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
FOR loop using indexes:
a
b
c
FOR loop using enumeration:
0
1
2
tuple
```

Could somebody explain where does an extra "tuple" come from in the second loop? While defined as function in Object.prototype, it is neither an own property of `x` object, nor included in `names` array.

I am using node.js version 0.8.20.

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/218196.

Comment: Thanx, I am aware. Thus the use of `Object.keys()`.

Comment: Thanx @FelixKling, seems you are right indeed. I forgot that enumerating Array also include Object.prototype's definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop goes over the properties of `x` (`Object.keys()` returns only own properties), while the second one goes over the properties or the **array** `names`, including the ones up in the prototype chain.

Thanks to **Jonathan Lonowski** for clarifications.

Comment: Thanks. I already did and it showed [Function] (as expected). Why is `tuple` omitted when I do `console.log(names)`? Why is it even included in `names` when it is not an Object's own property?

Comment: If I execute his code in Chrome, I get `Dump of names:
["a", "b", "c", tuple: function]`. Why ?

Comment: @Utopik That varies between browsers and the dev tools they offer. Some will try to recognize `Array`s and only list their elements while others will simply list everything (thus `tuple: function`).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys states "Returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties" so I still don't get why is `tuple` even included in `names` and moreover, why isn't it just element with index `3` (so that `names[3] == 'tuple'`).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, `for..in` is not enumerating object here, but an array that is a result of 'Object.keys()'.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek `Array`s are `Object`s (`Array`'s inherit from `Array.prototype`, which is an `Object` making them inherit `Object.prototype`). And, `Array`s have other properties besides their indexes. Most just aren't enumerable (e.g., `length`). In short: it's generally recommended to stick with basic `for` loops for `Array`s.

Comment: OK, now I get it. So the problem is not `Objects.keys()` returning `tuple` but enumerating it's result includes also `tuple` as it is defined in `Array`'s prototype chain. Please post this as full answer so I could accept, thanks.

Comment: I assume I could prevent `tuple` from being enumerated using `Object.defineProperty()` instead?

Comment: Yes; in this case `tuple` will be a property of `x`, i.e. will show up in the first loop.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, please post your comment as full answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Kuba mentioned above is not correct.

`Object.keys`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and other similar method would behave different sightly. Their behaviors are related to a property named `enumerable`.

I am going to dinner with my friends so I can only give you a helpful link illustrating it. So sorry.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. What is not correct and what you can't downvote?